# How to access a group of host names all at once in ansible?

Tags: ansible

I want to run a command like below:

```
- name: start the cluster
  command: "pcs cluster setup --start --name cluster01 --force qi-gfs2-01.never.lan qi-gfs2-02.never.lan qi-gfs2-03.never.lan"
  when: " 'is not currently running' in cluster_status.stderr "
```

And here is my inventory file:

```
[gfs2_hosts]
qi-gfs2-01.never.lan
qi-gfs2-02.never.lan
qi-gfs2-03.never.lan
```

For a small cluster with three nodes, I can hard code it in the playbook. But for a larger cluster, there should have a way that I can access all hostnames one by one in one command using a group variable. But after googling around, I didn't find a hint. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `groups` variable:

```
- name: start the cluster
  command: "pcs cluster setup --start --name cluster01 --force {{ groups['gfs2_hosts'] | join(' ') }}"
  when: " 'is not currently running' in cluster_status.stderr "
```

Read the 
[Accessing information about other hosts with magic variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#accessing-information-about-other-hosts-with-magic-variables) section from the official documentation for more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The document is really helpful.